# Omega Gambit For white

Tags: opening, gambits, 1.d4

My question is about Omega Gambit.

```
[Title "Omega gambit"]
[fen "rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1"]

1. d4 Nf6 2. e4 Nxe4
```

Is it too dangerous for white? what are the ideas for white? And what is the winning percentage for white? Is it still played among titled players?

Comment: Come on this is an insane opening !

Comment: @Niels I played it by mistake last night :P so i said wtf am i doing???!! and now i like to learn more about it

Comment: Perhaps (I've read somewhere) it's called "Omega gambit" because that's what White thinks at this point: "Omygosh, I've lost a pawn for nothing"

Comment: Here: http://www.chesscafe.com/text/mcgrew28.pdf (with several blitz games)

Comment: @leonbloy Thanks! "Omygosh gambit" is a more fitting name for this gambit! :D

Comment: A related gambit is the Blackmar-Diemer Gambit and it's a more serious gambit than the Omega Gambit. It has a decent scoring percentage for White in most lines. http://www.chessgames.com/perl/explorer?node=544615&move=3.5&moves=d4.d5.e4.dxe4.Nc3&nodes=10703.75972.288760.544614.544615

Comment: Related: the Roscher Gambit, http://chess.stackexchange.com/q/1010/167

Comment: @ETD yes almost identical

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is it too dangerous for white?

Yes.

> what are the ideas for white?

Try to use your open lines and get good piece play, I suppose. Black is already better, though (up a central pawn with no weaknesses), so you shouldn't expect to succeed.

> And what is the winning percentage for white?

In my database it is 19%.

> Is it still played among titled players?

No, and it never was (I can find only 2 games where it was played by someone with a rating over 2200).